# auto/configure not found error is given when running ./configure to compile vim from source

Tags: git, vim, sh

I cloned `vim` from the [official repo](https://github.com/vim/vim), and following the instructions I tried to run the `./configure` script. This however failed with the error `auto/configure not found`, thrown by the script in `src/configure` (which is called by the `configure` script in the root directory).

The file `auto/configure` is obviously there, so what may be causing this?

I use a zsh shell on Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I realised that the problem was caused by *incorrect file endings*.

Basically, I had the `core.autocrlf` option set to `true` globally, which caused all the file endings to be messed up, and for some reason the abovementioned problems.

After doing `git config --global core.autocrlf false` and recloning the repo from scratch the `configure` scripts run without problems.